# Dynamic bootstrap carousel with thumbnail navigation in PHP and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a dynamic bootstrap carousel with image thumbnails at the bottom. I went through several code snippets and answers which seems to be working in their demo and experimented those codes. I just got [the code in this link](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/ascensus/135500#html-tab-view) working but the thumbnail was too small. Here are the functions I wrote to make dynamic carousel...

```
//make image thumbnails
function make_image_previews ($con){
    $output = ''; 
    $count = 0;
    $result = make_query($con); //returns the images in database
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        if($count == 0){
            $output .= '<li data-target="#dynamic_slide_show" data-slide-to="'.$count.'" class="active"> 
            <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="'.$row['image'].'">
            </li>';
        }else{
            $output .= '<li data-target="#dynamic_slide_show" data-slide-to="'.$count.'"> 
            <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="'.$row['image'].'">
            </li>';
        }
        $count = $count + 1;
    }
    return $output;
}
```

And here is the html output in page source

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">     
    <div id="dynamic_slide_show" class="carousel slide light-shadow carousel-fade carousel-thumbnails" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img src="upload/protected_matrix-background-style-computer-virus-hacker-screen-wallpa-wallpaper-green-dominant-color-format-121069553.jpg" class="d-block w-100" />
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="upload/protected_photo-1515879218367-8466d910aaa4.jpg" class="d-block w-100" />
           </div>
           <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="upload/protected_UC-b6b17814-ad20-4509-8102-4efa70f6ee67.jpg" class="d-block w-100" />
           </div>    
       </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#dynamic_slide_show" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#dynamic_slide_show" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    <!--Carousel image preview-->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#dynamic_slide_show" data-slide-to="0" class="active"> 
            <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="upload/protected_matrix-background-style-computer-virus-hacker-screen-wallpa-wallpaper-green-dominant-color-format-121069553.jpg">
        </li>
        <li data-target="#dynamic_slide_show" data-slide-to="1"> 
           <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="upload/protected_photo-1515879218367-8466d910aaa4.jpg">
        </li>
        <li data-target="#dynamic_slide_show" data-slide-to="2"> 
          <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="upload/protected_UC-b6b17814-ad20-4509-8102-4efa70f6ee67.jpg">
        </li>    
    </ol>
  </div>                
  </div>
  </div>
<hr>
```

There was [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57013193/bootstrap-4-carousel-with-to-small-thumbnails) with the same problem but the code was different to what I have provided in the link at top. I tried the answer changing the code but I was able only to see the three underlines. How can I solve the problem of small thumbnails in my code?

**EDIT**
When I tried the CSS

```
.carousel-indicators {
  position: static;
}
.carousel-indicators>li {
    width: 100px
}
```

the thumbnail overflows onto the next row. As in following picture, horizontal line, (`<hr>` tag) is on the end of the row where the carousel is present

Comment: can you change your html to whatever you are echo with php, that way we can see the real problem and try to help you?

Comment: @Francisco do you mean the html content in page source?

Comment: yes, so that we can see your problem in action.

Comment: Ok. I have updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/setw7kn0/

You can set the images `width` by changing `.carousel-indicators > li` to whatever you want (in the example i have used `100px`). Also the `position: static;` in `.carousel-indicators` is to make the thumbnails stop overlapping the `carousel`.

Tell me if this is what you were looking for.

**EDIT:**

Well the reason that `.carousel-indicators` is overlapping the `hr` it's because `hr` shouldn't be placed directly inside `.row`, instead should be either inside a `column` inside a `row` or after the `.row` closing tag.

Also i have changed the `.carousel-indicators > li` `height` to `auto` so that you override the defaults `bootstrap` css, the default value of `bootstrap` is `height: 3px;` (so you are actually fighting bootstrap).

Comment: @Fransico The snippet you have provided seems to be working fine. But there seems to be problems in my machine. The thumbnails are positioned static but kind of overflowed in to the next row. If you want  more elaboration can you please say how to post a picture in comment section?